# Calling another objectStream.Write text macro within my macro isn't workiing

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8, adodb

So I'm creating a macro to output an UTF-8 encoded XML since the source text will sometimes involve Japanese or Chinese characters. I'm trying to break each section of the XML into different chunks so it's easier for me to edit but my call line isn't working. Since I'm not trained in programming and my knowledge is based on looking up VBA macro codes and tweaking them until I get the desired result, I'm stumped as to how to get my objStream macro to not error when calling another objStream line.

Thanks!

Here it is:

```
Sub Export_iTunes_XML()

Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

Dim FileName As String
FileName = "metadata.xml"

Dim Output As String
Output = FilePath & FileName

If Dir(Output, vbNormal) <> "" Then
    Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite?", vbOKCancel, "File Exists")
End If
If Answer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 'Create the stream
objStream.Open 'Initialize the stream
objStream.Position = 0 'Rest the position
objStream.Charset = "UTF-8" 'indicate the character encoding

objStream.WriteText "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCr
objStream.WriteText "      <title>" & Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("A3") & "</title>" & vbCr

If Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("P4") <> 0 Then Call LocaleTest2

objStream.WriteText "      <production_company>" & Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("H3") & "</production_company>" & vbCr
___________________________________________________________________________
Sub LocaleTest2()

Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

Dim FileName As String
FileName = "metadata.xml"

Dim Output As String
Output = FilePath & FileName

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 'Create the stream
objStream.Open 'Initialize the stream
objStream.Position = 0 'Rest the position
objStream.Charset = "UTF-8" 'indicate the character encoding

objStream.WriteText Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("P4")
objStream.CopyTo Output

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error, and on which line?

Comment: The error I'm receiving is a type mismatch error for the "objStream.CopyTo Output" line. Thanks!

Comment: @YowE3K - my bad for not reading through more carefully: I missed the same declaration/assignment was repeated when I was looking mainly at the `CopyTo` line...  Fixed in my answer and thanks for raising that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CopyTo` expects another stream object, not a string/file path. If you want `LocaleTest2` to write content to the same stream as is already open in `Export_iTunes_XML`, then you should pass the stream as a parameter when you call `LocaleTest2`.

Having made that change though, I'm not sure you get any benefit from breaking that out into a separate Sub.

```
Sub Export_iTunes_XML()

    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = "metadata.xml"

    Dim Output As String
    Output = FilePath & FileName

    If Dir(Output, vbNormal) <> "" Then
        Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite?", vbOKCancel, "File Exists")
    End If
    If Answer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 'Create the stream
    objStream.Open 'Initialize the stream
    objStream.Position = 0 'Rest the position
    objStream.Charset = "UTF-8" 'indicate the character encoding

    objStream.WriteText "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCr
    objStream.WriteText "      <title>" & Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("A3") & "</title>" & vbCr

    If Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("P4") <> 0 
        LocaleTest2 objStream '<<< pass the stream object
    End If

    objStream.WriteText "      <production_company>" & 
    Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("H3") & "</production_company>" & vbCr
    '....
End Sub


Sub LocaleTest2(objStream as Object)

    'write to the provided stream
    objStream.WriteText Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("P4")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim! I'm breaking out the section into it's own sub since I got an error for the process being too long. I know I can loop the information I'm trying to export row by row but since my knowledge is limited, I'm having a difficult time. I also prefer to write it all out just so I can understand how each line works. Again, I don't have a background in programming so all this takes me a good while to understand.

Comment: OK - typically if you're running into "procedure too long" errors then that's a red flag: at the least having that much code makes it difficult to maintain and/or debug.

Comment: Would it be best to breaks those sections into their own modules as opposed to having different subs on one?

Comment: You're just moving the problem around at that point - if you have that much code it usually indicates a fundamental problem with your underlying approach.  For example are you hard-coding meta-data into your VBA which would be better stored on a worksheet (e.g. a list of ranges and corresponding tag names)?  It's difficult to know from the code you posted why you are hitting that limit.  If you find you have split out single lines of code into their own Sub (and they only get called once) then that's not the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much. I had a print script that worked perfectly for the XML I'm attempting to output but since I'm now working with source text that contains Japanese and Chinese characters, I'm trying to tweak my macro with an ADODB stream so that the xml file is outputted to UTF-8. I appreciate all the help and information.

Answer (score 0):

The code would to be like this.

```
Sub Export_iTunes_XML()
    Dim vR(), myText As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Output As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long

    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    FileName = "metadata.xml"
    Output = FilePath & FileName
    Set Ws = Sheets("RawMetadata")


    If Dir(Output, vbNormal) <> "" Then
        Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite?", vbOKCancel, "File Exists")
    End If
    If Answer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
    vR(n) = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
    vR(n) = "      <title>" & Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("A3") & "</title>"
    With Ws
        If Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("P4") <> 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = .Range("p4")
        End If
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = "      <production_company>" & .Range("H3") & "</production_company>"
    End With

    myText = Join(vR, vbCrLf)
    TransToUTF8 Output, myText
End Sub
Sub TransToUTF8(myfile As String, str As String)
 Dim objStream As Object
 Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    With objStream
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText str
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Addition**

```
Sub Export_iTunes_XML()

 Dim XMLFileName As String
 Dim output4 As String
 Dim range4 As Range
 Dim vDB, vR(), vResult()
 Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
 Dim myText As String

 XMLFileName = "metadata.xml"
 FolderName4 = Sheets("RawMetadata").Range("D42") & "_" & Sheets("iTunes").Range("B8") & ".itmsp"
 FolderPath4 = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & FolderName4

MkDir FolderPath4
output4 = FolderPath4 & "\" & XMLFileName

 vDB = Sheets("iTunes").Range("A1:g936")


For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    If vDB(i, 7) = "ON" Then
        ReDim vR(1 To 6)
        For j = 1 To 6
            vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To n)
        vResult(n) = Join(vR, "")
    End If
Next i
    myText = Join(vResult, vbCrLf)
    TransToUTF8 output4, myText

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Dy.Lee for the macro. I'm testing this out now to see how it works. I wanted to share my original #print macro so that this thread can see what I was trying to transition from. The macro I had went row by row and outputted the cell value if the row line was "ON" (apologies if this is obvious from the code I provided).  Like I stated before, it worked exactly how I wanted to, with exporting an XML file to the desired output folder but once I started to receive source text in Japanese and Chinese, the outputted XML started showing ???? for all foreign language characters.

Comment: @ChuckCT36:  "utf-8"  change "unicode"  and test code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. It works perfectly! Not only that, I'm able to follow your code and learn little by little on how it all works. Thanks again!